# awk find string and under line print

Tags: linux, shell, awk, nawk

I have data that looks like this:

```
test AA=bddddbs
result=1
cell AA=bnnndb5
result=2
cell1 BB=bnrrndb
result=3
```

Please help. Find `AA=string`.

```
test AA=bddddbs;result=1
cell AA=bnnndb5;result=2
```

I am use below command and result fail.

```
nawk '/AA=/{val=$1;next} {print val,$1}' infile
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This question tagged with `shell`, `awk` is definitely related to programming only.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk -v OFS=';' '/AA=/{rec=$0; getline; print rec, $0}' file

test AA=bddddbs;result=1
cell AA=bnnndb5;result=2
```